# datomic pull api pattern to exclude ident

Tags: datomic

I have a schema like this:

```
:user/first-name
:user/last-name
:user/password
:user/groups
;; assume there are x more ident
:user/email
```

I'm pulling this by doing:

```
(d/pull db '[*] some-id)
```

Apparently this will also pull `:user/password` which I don't want, and doing this is cumbersome:

```
(d/pull db 
        [:user/first-name :user/last-name ;; all fields except :user/password] 
        some-id)
```

Is there anyway to do something like this:

```
(d/pull db ['* (except :user/password)] some-id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use datomic's filter function to filter out datoms you don't need from db value.

In your case something like

```
(d/pull (filter db #(not (= (second %2) :user/password))) some-id)
```